Flutter webapp debugged locally trying to call firebase functions from default region
I am creating a Flutter webapp integrated with firebase (and firestore):

A Flutter webapp that I can debug locally, in Chrome
A Firebase project in a region X, with firestore and functions deployed to that same region X

The functions are firebase functions v2, some are http (onRequest) and some are callable (onCall).
When I debugged the webapp for the first time, neither of the function types worked.
I provided a corsHandler for the http functions, and that did the trick.
However, for the callable functions, I thought no cors handling was necessary. However I noticed that if I deploy the functions to us-central1, instead of my region X, they work as expected. And if I deploy them back to my desired region, I get this error in the chrome console (I hid my app id and function name, but the rest is exactly the trace):
https://us-central1-.cloudfunctions.net/' from origin 'http://localhost:57768' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
So I assume the obvious solution would be to get my webapp (which I am debugging locally) to run as if deployed to my region, instead of us-central1. All search results I am seeing talk about firebase emulator, that I need to install this or that package... but I suspect I am just missing some configuration on flutter side. How can I do that?

For anyone interested, I found the solution in another stackoverflow question:
Firebase Callable Function + CORS
What I was missing was, on the client side where I call my function, to get the instance for a specific region:
FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'your-region').httpsCallable('your-function');

instead of
FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('your-function');

